# What is the reason why Android app bundle filename is created with number postfix like 'apks/splits/base-arm64_v8a_2.apk'?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I don't know the reason why all abi output for bundle have a suffix of '_2' like the following image.

[image]

My gradle script used for multiple apk
 
and now I wanna apply to app bundle.

So there is part of build.gradle like below.

```
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    bundle {
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
```

But I think the problem is not for the script.
Does anyone know why the suffix is created?

Answer (score 1):

Bundletool creates multiple APKs that target different Android SDK versions to ensure the smallest app size per type of device.

There are in this case two "base-master" and per-ABI APKs created, so one is suffixed with _2 to differentiate them.

You're in general not expected to manually extract the APKs from the 
.apks file. You can use bundletool to directly install or extract the correct APKs for a given device.

Comment: You're right. I tried to install `apks` after I created it through the command that is `bundletool build-apks --bundle=./app.aab --output=output.apks`. But when I tried to find the difference, it's totally the same size after unzipping. Do you know any guidance document for the processing of bundletools how it works internally?

Comment: The compression of the native libraries will differ: on Android M, the native libraries can remain uncompressed in the APK which allows the Android platform to mmap them directly from the APK without having to extract them first. Try comparing the output of "unzip -lv xxx.apk".